# Breadcrumbs to equation number in Lyx

Tags: equations, formatting, lyx

I am using Lyx and I am a novice but I am hooked to Lyx. I have zero background in Latex.

Question 1:
How can I add breadcrumbs ....... to my equation numbers in Lyx so that when I view a pdf, I get the equation followed by ......... followed by equation number.

Question 2:
How do I make my equation numbers (17-1) where 17 is the chapter number and 1 is the first equation in chapter 17 in Lyx.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Do not ask two questions at the same time, this does not allow search engines to do a targeted search. If you have two questions, ask them separately.

Comment: Apologies and thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Equation numbers displayed as you want are simple to obtain, redefining `\theequation`.

As to the dots to the equation number, you can load the `dotseqn` package, but be aware that

1. it works only for the `equation` environment (and `eqnarray`, not recommended for spacing reasons,  not with multilined environments from `amsmath;
2. the equation environments will be flushleft.

Demo:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dotseqn}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter-\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{5}

Some text. Some more text.
\begin{equation}\label{eq-test}
  x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}\label{eq-test1}
\Delta & =b^2-4ac \\
  x & = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\label{eq-test2}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works. Only if there was a way to have equation (5-1) be centered like the other equations with the breadcrumbs.

Comment: I upvoted but since I am a newbie my vote does not show :(